# Typescript: get parameters type of a method in a composition class

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, typescript-generics

Hello there fellow TS community. So here's a problem: imagine we have a composition interface like this:

```
type IWorker = {
    serviceTask: IServiceTask,
    serviceSomethingElse: IServiceColorPicker
}

type IServiceTask = {
    doSomething: (arg1: number) => Promise<void>;
}

type IServiceSomethingElse = {
    doSomething1: (params: Record<string, any>) => Promise<string>;
}
```

We also have implementation for these interfaces, but I just skipped them here. Lemme now if you need those!
Anyways so let's say we have a function that runs one of the methods in a nodejs worker thread:

```
const runInWorker<T extends keyof IWorker, K extends keyof IWorker[T], P extends ????>(parameters: {workerService: T, serviceMethod: K, methodParams: P}) => {
    const worker: IWorker = new Worker();
    worker[workerService][serviceMethod].call(this, methodParams)
    ...
}
```

This `runInWorker` function has three arguments:

1. Name of service we're about to run - `workerService`: `serviceTask` or `serviceSomethingElse`
2. Name of method of a service - `serviceMethod`: `doSomething` or `doSomething1`
3. Parameters to pass into that method. `methodParams`: `number` | `Record<string, any>`. I've tried the `Parameters<IWorker[T][K]>` generic but it doesn't resolve to parameters - says 'type IWorker[T][K] doesn not satisfy constraint (...args: any) => any'- which is Parameters generic's type argument constraints

So  I have 2 questions:

1. How to get rid of "call doesn't exist on type IWorker[T][K]" TS error?
2. How do I infer argument types of my methods?

Thanks!

With question 1 I've expected methods to be callable so I've tried just calling them with
`worker[workerService][serviceMethod]` but of course it didn't help

With question 2 as I said I've tried to use Parameters generic but looks like it's no good with other generics like that - it just doesn't know those types yet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript cannot see that all fields on `IWorker` needs to be methods. You can either have some constraint on the level of type signature, or you can make a kind of constraint by having conditional type. The latter can be implemented like this. Swap the `Parameters` type with

```
type GetParameters<T> = T extends (...args: any) => any ? Parameters<T> : never
```

Here you check whether `T` is actually a function. If you would declare a non-function field on `IWorker`, then the third parameter would have `never` type, that is a type for you can't have any value, that means you couldn't make a call to such a function that would typecheck.

Thus, by having this signature, you can make the calls:

```
function runInWorker2<T extends keyof IWorker, K extends keyof IWorker[T]>(parameters: {workerService: T, serviceMethod: K, methodParams: GetParameters<IWorker[T][K]>}) {
// implementation
}
const t = runInWorker2({workerService: "serviceTask", serviceMethod: "doSomething", methodParams: [3]})
const t2 = runInWorker2({workerService: "serviceSomethingElse", serviceMethod: "doSomething1", methodParams: [{x: "y"}]})
```